# CSS content resizing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an image fill the device screen in CSS but i'm having no luck. The image is in an after: pseudo element and content tag. I can't use the image as a background because it has to lay over the html. Any Ideas?

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
body:after{
    content: url(images/IGOVERLAYPAPI.png); 
    position:fixed;
    max-width:100%; 
    height:auto; 
    z-index:444;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to force an element to cover the dimensions of the viewport, try:

```
body:after{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: That didn't do the trick, I played around with the image size as well but had no luck. The image is aligned properly on the left and top sides but the bottom and right sides stretch to it's original dimensions.